# C# Task which returns a value

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I'm trying to run a function in a task but I'm doing something wrong.
Heres an example:

```
var t = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateResult(2));

static int GenerateResult(int i)
{ 
return i; 
}
```

In the end `Console.WriteLine(t);`
This returns:

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int32]

I want i to be 2.
What am I doing wrong here? :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are printing the task object that you created. For result, see `.Result` property:

`Console.WriteLine(t.Result);`

Comment: Oh my god, how did I not see this!
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `t.Result`.

For example

```
Console.WriteLine(t.t.Result);
```

Your code essentially looks like this:

```
Task<int> t = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateResult(2));
```

And when you write `Console.WriteLine(t);` you are actually just printing the `Task` and not the `integer`. To be able to access the result you need to add `.Result`.